# Is there a way to overline text in Pages for the iPad?

Tags: pages, text-input

I use my iPad for note taking in my statistics class and I need to create an overline for the sample mean (which has a line over an  x  called x-bar) and I can't find a way to get it to work in Pages.

I was able to get the Greek keyboard for all the other math symbols I needed, but this one I can't figure out.

Comment: If all else fails, you can just copy this: x̄

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for "math symbols" in the app store, you will find a number of apps designed to create such things for pasting into other apps.  Otherwise copy/paste from an existing note is solution I think.